# Can FQDN be replaced by IP address in TDengine?

Tags: fqdn, tdengine

We built a test environment with TDengine, with a 4 nodes cluster. We configured the FQDN(Fully Qualified Domain Name) according the document. It's OK.

Now we have a requirement to use IP, not FQDN. However, I didn't find the instructions through the web.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply replace host name with IP, it works in my test env.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `fqdn` option in `taos.cfg` file as ip, for example:

```
fqdn 192.168.1.10
```

And set the `firstEp` in client or another dnode with:

```
firstEp 192.168.1.10:6030
```